How can I have different value and text in CascadeChoiceParameter in Jenkins pipeline
Currently I am rendering the CascadeChoiceParameter with a groovy script that returns a list:
['1', '2', '3']

So in the drop-down I see the values as the lables/text of the choices:
1
2
3

Is there a way to have labels different from the values? i.e:
First
Second
Third

I tried this but doesn't seem to work:
['1': 'First', '2': 'Second', '3':'Third']


Sorry, not possible to achieve in the current version of Jenkins. Why not leave it as "First, Second,..." and get the numbers through map indexing during pipeline execution?

Because we have a complex legacy code that is used in multiple places to render this drop-down and it's digested in many places. So on one hand I would like to be able to display additional information, on the other hand I don't want to change every place the value is used to cut the additional data (my real values are ASG names and the display would add some info about them in () after the value) and the additional info is dynamic.
